# How can I prevent absolute position from overlapping while using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I need to display each div without any overlaps, the main div is using bootstrap `col-*`, this same div contains other divs with `absolute` position, **I need to be clear that I cannot altern the height and the width of any div outside `.element` divs** (which means width, height of `100%` or `auto` can still be used).

Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lmt1u1uw/6/

```css
.layout {
  position: relative;
}

.element,
.elements {
  position: absolute;
}

.layout-1 .background {
  background: #4dadc9;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.layout-1 .text {
  transform: translate(30px, 60px);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
}

.layout-2 .background {
  background: red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.layout-2 .text {
  transform: translate(170px, 200px);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="region col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="layout layout-1">
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="element background"></div>
      <div class="element text">Magic soak into my spine.</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="region col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="layout layout-2">
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="element background"></div>
      <div class="element text">The dreams maker gonna make you mad.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet the two `.region` are on top of each other on responsive and shouldn't overlap, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Set the position of layouts to relative if you don't want them to overlap.

Comment: @NiteshRana See snippet, `.layout {position: relative;}` is already on relative.

Comment: For layouts class... it is absolute.?

Comment: @NiteshRana `.element, .elements {position: absolute;}` has to stay absolute, otherwise there would be no point in that, I'm trying to avoid overlaps while keeping these in absolute position.

Comment: is there any reason why you need `.elements` with position `absolute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two `.elements` need to be display:block and have a specified width/height in order to float around each other:

have a look a my fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmt1u1uw/7/

This should do the trick.

Comment: hmm I see there's not any other alternative avoiding to specify the width and the height ?

Comment: at least you need display:inline-block and height - there will be overlapping otherwise.

Comment: I'm taking a look at flexbox, maybe there'll be some discoveries, I will keep you up to date if i find anything

Comment: This will get you started on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I've read about that :) but I couldn't manage to not specify any height or width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150408/discussion-between-mtness-and-lindow).